# Recover qubits used in an actual computation

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

How do I recover from a certain `job_id` in the IBM backends which qubits where used?

I would be interested to know if for instance, in a batch of say 50 jobs, 25 of them are run in qubits 0 and 1 but the other half in  say 5 or 7.

Comment: I think the `initial_layout` parameter in **transpile** function would allow you to specify just what you are looking for. This allows you to map the virtual qubits used in the circuit to the physical qubits in the processor. You may look at the documentation [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html)